# Regex and LINQ extract group by group name

Tags: regex, vb.net, linq

I have a SQL sintax in the form of a string in which there are some parameters written in a standard way `"<parameter1>, <parameter2>"`.
Then i have another string with the parameters values written in a standard way as well: `"Parameter1=123; Parameter2=aaa"`.

I need to match the parameters in the first SQL with the values in the second one.

What I have so far:`

```
Dim BodySQL = "Blablabal WHERE X=<Parameter1> AND Y=<Parameter2>"
Dim vmp As RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches("Parameter1=2555; Parameter2 = 12/02/2021", "([\w ]+)=([\w ]+)")
Dim vmc As RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(BodySQL, "(?<=\<).+?(?=\>)")

    For Each vm As RegularExpressions.Match In vmc
        Dim Vl As String = (From m As RegularExpressions.Match In vmp
                            Where m.Groups(1).Value.Trim = vm.Value.ToString).Select(Of String)(Function(f) f.Groups(2).Value).ElementAt(0).Trim

        BodySQL = BodySQL.Replace(vm.Value, Vl)
    Next
```

It works for the first parameter, but then i get

```
"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index'"
```

Can I please ask why?

Comment: Either `m.Groups` does not have at least 2 elements, or `f.Groups` does not have at least 3 elements, or there is no `ElementAt(0)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was already under these assumptions :D. The thing is, i'm a noob at both REGEX and LINQ and i don't know it this is the right way. also, there are for sure 2 elements in m and 3 in f. I checked in the debuger. About the elementat(0), shouldn't there be one if the first two conditions are met?

Comment: Please check this code - https://ideone.com/MoF6p8. It is not compiling in Mono, try i n Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the keys and values with one regex from the `param=value` strings, create a dictionary out of them, and then use `Regex.Replace` to replace the matches with the dictionary values:

```vb
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
' ...
Dim BodySQL = "Blablabal WHERE X=<Parameter1> AND Y=<Parameter2>"

Dim args As New Dictionary(Of String, String)(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
' (StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) makes the dictionary keys case insensitive

For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches("PARAMETER1=2555; Parameter2 = 12/02/2021", "(\S+)\s*=\s*([^;]*[^;\s])")
    args.Add(match.Groups(1).Value, match.Groups(2).Value)
Next

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(BodySQL, "<([^<>]*)>",
    Function(match)
        Return If(args.ContainsKey(match.Groups(1).Value), args(match.Groups(1).Value), match.Value)
    End Function))
```

Output:

```
Blablabal WHERE X=2555 AND Y=12/02/2021
```

The `(\S+)\s*=\s*([^;]*[^;\s])` pattern matches

- `(\S+)` - captures into Group 1 any one or more non-whitespace chars (the key value)
- `\s*=\s*`  - a `=` char enclosed with zero or more whitespace chars
- `([^;]*[^;\s])` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `;` and then one char other than `;` and whitespace (the value, it cannot be empty with this pattern. If you want it to be possible to match empty values, you will need to remove `[^;\s]` and then use `Trim()` on the `match.Groups(2).Value` in the code.)

The `<([^<>]*)>` regex matches

- `<` - a `<` char (do not escape this char in any regex flavor please, it is never a special regex metachar)
- `([^<>]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `<` and `>`
- `>` - a literal `>` char.

Since the key is in Group 1 and `<` and `>` on both ends are consumed, the `<` and `>` are removed when replacing with the found value.
zero or more chars other than `>` and `<` between `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory. You are trying to access an array or List and specifying an index value that is either negative or larger than the largest index available.

```
.ElementAt(0) / m.Groups(1) / f.Groups(2)
```

My guess is that one of them might go out of bounds. Try to debug it with a breakpoint and check the values of your variables.

Answer (score -2):

This is what i did with your code:

```
Dim vmc = "\<(.*?)\>"
```

> i changed this regex so that it could also give me the "<>"

```
Dim BodySQL = "Blablabal WHERE X=<Parameter1> AND Y=<Parameter2>"

Dim args As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches("Parameter1=2555; Parameter2 = 12/02/2021", "(\S+)\s*=\s*(\S[^;]+)")
```

> i changed the regex expression to exclude the ";"

```
    args.Add(match.Groups(1).Value, match.Groups(2).Value)
Next
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(BodySQL, vmc,
     Function(match As Match)
                 Return If(args.ContainsKey(match.Groups(1).Value), args(match.Groups(1).Value), match.Value)
             End Function))
```

And now i have what i needed. Thank you a lot :)

Output:

```
WHERE X = 2555,Y = 12/02/2021
```

Comment: Why did i get a -1 on this? It does exactly what i wanted it to do...